# Совмещение синтаксиса 2-х языков программирования.

Tags: php, actionscript

Доброго времени суток. Я программист Action Script 3.0 и Php. Безусловно, это два очень динамичных и мощных языка программирования. И я хочу совместить их в своём flash- приложении, но как это сделать я не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в синтаксис Action Script 3.0 всавить код Php.

Comment: Во-первых -- никак (вариант с написанием интерпретатора php на ActionScript оставляем за скобками). А во-воторых -- нафиг. Только php в javascript'е и не хватало.

Comment: Почитайте про Flex, я думаю это то что вам нужно, правда реализовано немного не так, как вы себе это представляете.

Comment: Правильней будет генерировать данные на стороне сервера при помощи ПХП и передавать данные посредством допустим xml или json во флеш (AS)

Answer (score 5):

ActionScript в виде SWF выполняется Flash Player-ом на стороне клиента, PHP - интерпретатором на стороне сервера. Поэтому прямо вставить одно в другое мало реально.

В типовых задачах достаточно средствами PHP генерировать данные в виде XML на сервере и передавать их в ActionScript на клиенте.

Comment: Скорее всего, ТС это и имел в виду.